Convert Async Downloaded file with SSH.NET To MemoryStream
I am using SSH.NET (Renci.SshNet) library to work with an SFTP server.
I want to save the downloaded file as a file in memory.
This is My Service Class :
public class SshServices
{
    private static SftpClient? s_sftpClient; //using Renci.SshNet
    public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        s_sftpClient = new SftpClient("test.rebex.net", "demo", "password");
        await s_sftpClient.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        if (s_sftpClient != null && s_sftpClient.IsConnected)
        {
            var serverAddress = @"\readme.txt";
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var result = s_sftpClient.BeginDownloadFile(serverAddress, stream);
            do
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
            }
            while (result == null || !result.IsCompleted);

            if (result != null && result.IsCompleted) s_sftpClient.EndDownloadFile(result);
            s_sftpClient.Disconnect();

            stream = (MemoryStream)result; //Result is Okey - but i cant Convert it to stream
            return stream;                 //And Return it
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

The Problem Is I cant Return This Result

you probably just want stream.Position = 0; return stream; ? however, a loop with a delay seems overkill here - I wonder if we can exploit the async-callback API to get signalling instead

@MarcGravell TaskFactory.FromAsync?

The problem, of course, is that your result is an IAsyncResult and not a stream at all! You passed stream into BeginDownloadFile, so it should already have the file contents in it. As Marc said, you probably just need to rewind it

@canton7 Thank you for your time. What is your solution?

@canton7 IIRC there isn't full CT support for that; it might need to be done manually - something like var pending = new TaskCompletionSource();, using (cancellationToken.Register(static s => ((TaskCompletionSource)s!).TrySetCanceled(), pending)) {, var result = s_sftpClient.BeginDownloadFile(serverAddress, stream, delegate { pending.TrySetResult(); });, await pending.Task;, s_sftpClient.EndDownloadFile(result);, }

@YasimYasin To do what Marc said: remove the stream = (MemoryStream)result; line, and add stream.Position = 0;

@MarcGravell goddd, how it possible?? ... thank you. I have to read about it(stream.position), I really don't understand how it happened. But it worked

in short: the BeginDownloadFile code is already writing to the stream, but a MemoryStream is like a cassette tape - if you write to it, you're left at the end, so after it has written, we "rewind" it, by setting the location back to the start: stream.Position = 0; - then we simply hand that stream back to the caller: return stream;

@MarcGravell To be honest this goes all the way down to the bottom: there is no proper async support in SSH.Net, it just hands off to another thread, which calls the reader synchronously. See https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/Sftp/SftpFileReader.cs

@MarcGravell In the continuation of the question... can you see this link please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78699912/downloaded-audio-file-by-ssh-and-returned-by-the-service-but-api-cannot-retu
